# Permission Denied: cd into directory

Tags: linux, permissions, chrome-os

I'm using a Chromebook and would like to navigate inside the Android container via the shell. The container is mounted at the path `/run/containers/android_XXXXX`. When trying to `cd` into the directory, I'm told `Permission Denied`. I've tried running the command as `sudo`, but for some reason the `cd` command becomes inaccessible. I've ran `chmod u+x` on the directory, but no dice.

What steps can I take from here?

I've ran `stat` on the directory, which returns the following:

```
  File: ‘android_XXXXXX/’
  Size: 80              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fh/15d  Inode: 59640       Links: 3
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (655360/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (655360/ UNKNOWN)
Context: u:object_r:tmpfs:s0
Access: 2016-10-31 04:04:52.680000040 +0000
Modify: 2016-10-31 04:04:52.200000040 +0000
Change: 2016-10-31 04:44:54.990001186 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Since you're talking about a permission problem, where is your `whoami` and the permission listing for the directory in question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The directory is `drwx------` so only someone whose uid is `655350` (which is not listed in the password file) can read it or enter it.

`sudo cd` not being able to find the `cd` command is expected, it is a builtin to the shell. If it wasn't builtin then it wouldn't work. Say your current shell has a process ID of 54000, you ran the /bin/cd command, it might be PID 54309. It would change the directory for process 54309, and then exit. process 54000 would still be in its original directory.

`chmod u+x` alters `user (owner)` permission.

What you want is `sudo chmod go+rx /run/containers/android_XXXXX`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I haven't ever seen the 'go' parameter before. Thanks for clarifying the behaviour of PIDs in the shell.

Comment: `g` is `group` and `o` is `other`, I was just changing them both at the same time. Almost certainly I could have used o+rx

Comment: Ah, I've got you. That's certainly useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to checking permissions like @icarus mentioned, you also need to check your ACLs (Access Control Lists) with `getfacl` to make sure that there aren't any rules overriding the basic file access privelages.

NOTE: If `getfacl` doesn't exist on your system, them it probably isn't the issue.

---

Example ACL that shouldn't be an issue.

```bash
$ getfacl test/
```

```
# file: test/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

This indicates that there are no additional ACL rules applied, other then the standard POSIX access rules. You can see that it matches the output of `ls -ald` in terms of permissions. (The `-d` argument to `ls` tells it to show you the directory itself, not its contents.)

```bash
$ ls -ald test/
```

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  8 19:11 test/
```

Example of a ACL that could cause you issues.

```bash
$ getfacl test/
```

```
# file: test/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mc:r--
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

```bash
$ ls -ald test/
```

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root root 4096 May  8 19:11 test/
```

In this case, looking at the output of `ls -ald`, you wouldn't think there would be an issue. However, because ACL rules apply over POSIX rules, the user `mc` would be unable to change into the directory due to the lack of executable permissions for him, dispite the fact that the others permission set would otherwise give them to `mc`.

Something to note though, the owner permissions seem to take president over all other ACL rules, and I believe the same goes for the group owner permissions.

The Arch Wiki has more information about ACL's. Check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Access_Control_Lists if you are intersted in learning more about them.

---

Understandably, you may not want to always check `getfacl` to see if that is your issue, or you may forget to do so. Fortunately, `ls -al` does tell you when there are additional ACL rules applied. If you take a look at the output of `ls -al`, you can see a `+` at the end of the list of permission bits whenever there are ACL rules applied, and it does not show otherwise (at least that appers to be the case in my short testing).

TLDR: If you see a `+` in the permissions list from `ls -al`, check the Access Control List (`getfacl`).